# Erro ao usar "maior que" em comando select com case

Tags: mysql, select

Estou tentando executar o seguinte comando select:

```
SELECT 
estoque.id,
produto.id,
produto.descricao PRODUTO,
case saida.quant when > 0 then (estoque.quant + sum(saida.quant)) else estoque.quant end ESTOQUE
FROM estoque, saida, produto
join produto on estoque.idProduto = produto.id
join saida on estoque.id = saida.idEstoque
where estoque.idUnidade = '0'
group by estoque.id
```

Recebo um erro na linha do case onde tem o símbolo `>`. Diz que não é permitido ele estar lá.

Minha intenção é que, caso `saida.quant` seja maior que zero, ele soma com `estoque.quant`, quando for menor que zero, lista apenas `estoque.quant`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Segundo a documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html), a sintaxe da sua *query* está incorreta. Deveria ser algo desta forma:

```
CASE case_value
    WHEN when_value THEN statement_list
    [WHEN when_value THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

O que dá pra fazer, é inverter a ordem da comparação e assim não será preciso mais do `>`. Veja abaixo:

```
SELECT 
estoque.id,
produto.id,
produto.descricao PRODUTO,
case saida.quant when 0 then estoque.quant else (estoque.quant + sum(saida.quant)) end ESTOQUE
FROM estoque, saida, produto
join produto on estoque.idProduto = produto.id
join saida on estoque.id = saida.idEstoque
where estoque.idUnidade = '0'
group by estoque.id
```

Caso queira considerar valores negativos, pode ser feito desta forma segundo sua mesma lógica porém com a sintaxe correta. Veja:

```
case when saida.quant>0 then estoque.quant else (estoque.quant + sum(saida.quant)) end...
```

Comment: Como saber então se é maior que zero ou menor?

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo é possível que seja menor?!  A logica está que se for 0 faça algo senão, considere todos os valores. Vou editar pra melhorar isso.